# SK3DNode not rotating

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit

I have a 3D sphere model saved as a dae file and loaded to xcode.

Problem is I cannot get it spinning/rotating - it just stays static... I've tried several ways, even tried to get the camera to move around it.

```
SCNScene *model = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"model3.dae"];
SK3DNode *node = [[SK3DNode alloc] initWithViewportSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];

//workaround
id s1 = [node valueForKey:@"_scnRenderer"];
NSLog(@"%@", s1);

node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:node.frame.size.width/2];

node.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
node.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;

node.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[node setScnScene:model];

//THIS IS THE PART! I cannot get it to spin around
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"rotation"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithSCNVector4:SCNVector4Make(1, 2, 3, M_PI * 2)];
rotationAnimation.duration = 1;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
[model.rootNode addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:nil];

//camera
SCNCamera *camera = [SCNCamera camera];
camera.xFov = 0;
camera.yFov = 0;
camera.zNear = 0.0;
camera.zFar = 10.0;
SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
cameraNode.camera = camera;
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 5);
[model.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];

node.pointOfView = cameraNode;
[world addChild:node];
```

Any ideas? Basically I want to try get the 3D model moving around inside the SK3DNode. Hope this makes sense. Think spinning planet.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modifying the transform (by adding an animation, for instance) of the root node of a scene has no effect because the camera is held by a child node of that root node. The relative transform between the sphere and the camera stays the same. You should add an animation to the camera node or to the sphere node instead.

Comment: Thank you. Yes applying the animation to the camera worked, I had to do it at the end of the setup. How do I get the sphere node?

Comment: Never mind, I guessed it...  thanks for your help!   SCNNode *n = [model.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"Icosphere" recursively:YES];